# How do I find the diameter of a binary tree?

Tags: java, tree

```
public class Diameter {
    
    // Klasse BinaryTree nicht modifizieren!
    public static class BinaryTree {
        int value;
        BinaryTree left;
        BinaryTree right;

        BinaryTree(int value) {
            this(value, null, null);
        }

        BinaryTree(int value, BinaryTree left, BinaryTree right) {
            this.value = value;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }

    public static int diameter(BinaryTree tree) {
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        case1();
        case2();
        case3();
        case4();
        case5();
        case6();
        case7();
    }

    // TestfÃ¤lle nicht modifizieren!
    public static void case1() {
        BinaryTree root = new BinaryTree(1,
                new BinaryTree(3,
                        new BinaryTree(7,
                                new BinaryTree(8,
                                        new BinaryTree(9),
                                        null),
                                null),
                        new BinaryTree(4,
                                null,
                                new BinaryTree(5,
                                        null,
                                        new BinaryTree(6)))),
                new BinaryTree(2)
        );
        System.out.println("Case 1: Solution should be 6 -- " + diameter(root));
    }
    
    public static void case2() {
        BinaryTree root = new BinaryTree(1);
        System.out.println("Case 2: Solution should be 0 -- " + diameter(root));
    }
    
    public static void case3() {
        BinaryTree root = new BinaryTree(1,
                new BinaryTree(2),
                null);
        System.out.println("Case 3: Solution should be 1 -- " + diameter(root));
    }
    
    public static void case4() {
        BinaryTree root = new BinaryTree(1,
                new BinaryTree(2),
                new BinaryTree(3));
        System.out.println("Case 4: Solution should be 2 -- " + diameter(root));
    }
    
    public static void case5() {
        BinaryTree root = new BinaryTree(1,
                new BinaryTree(2,
                        new BinaryTree(4),
                        null),
                new BinaryTree(3));
        System.out.println("Case 5: Solution should be 3 -- " + diameter(root));
    }

    public static void case6() {
        BinaryTree root = new BinaryTree(1,
                new BinaryTree(2,
                        new BinaryTree(3,
                                new BinaryTree(4,
                                        new BinaryTree(5,
                                                new BinaryTree(6,
                                                        null,
                                                        new BinaryTree(7)),
                                                null),
                                        null),
                                null),
                        null),
                null);
        System.out.println("Case 6: Solution should be 6 -- " + diameter(root));
    }

    public static void case7() {
        System.out.println("Case 7: Solution should be 0 -- " + diameter(null));
    }

}
```

I have to programm The diameter of a binary tree is the longest path in a binary tree. The path is defined in the same way as for graphs. Note that the path does not necessarily have to go through the root.

Write a diameter function in the Diameter class that gets a binary tree and returns the diameter of the tree.

Each node consists of an integer value, a left child left, and a right child right. Each child is either a node again or null

How can I implement it in my programm ? My idea was:

```
public int diameter (Node root)
{
    if (root == null) return 0;
    else return Math.max (
        diameter (root.left), 
        Math.max (
            diameter (root.right),
            height (root.left) + height (root.right) + 1));
}

public int height (Node root)
{
    if (root == null) return 0;
    else return 1 + Math.max (height (root.left), height (root.right));
}
```

Comment: You will have to keep the max diameter seen so far for a subtree somewhere and then you can compare the diameter including the node plus max diameter seen from left and right subtree, if that new diameter is greater than max so far then you would have to keep updating it each node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do depth first traverse and increase height each level. And pick maximum from left or right. But also we keep tracking `left+right` and pick the maximum one.

```
public static int max = 0;
public static int diameter(BinaryTree root, int height) {
    if (root == null) return height-1;

    int left = diameter(root.left, height + 1);
    int right = diameter(root.right, height + 1);
        
    int diameter = left+right-height*2; 
    max = max < diameter ? diameter : max;
        
    return Math.max(left,right);
}
```

Call it this way:

```
max=0;
diameter(root,0);
```

Comment: I think, your solution will produce wrong answer, can you check the case when one of the deeper subtree will produce maximum diameter?

Comment: I've updated the code. Previously in if clause height was not subtracted..